# Open video automatically when the first ends ( video.js , shadowbox.js )

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

I used shadowbox.js and video.js files for my mobile site. I like work on the box feature. I have a video in the first box and a text in the second one. I need when the video in the first box ends the second one open autoamtically. It's javascript code so I just need to know the right strings code so I could replace the file.

Thank you very much .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `ended` event like:

```
videojs("example_video_1").on("ended", function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/U989U/1/**